# Azure Dynamic Inventory not fetching resource group failed with status code 404

Tags: azure, ansible

Just started working on ansible dynamic inventory for azure, followed steps given by Azure documentation.

Created Service Principle with scope over below 2 resource group(redacted the names) When I am trying with the first resource group(service principle has scope over its subscription) I get the output of the virtual machines but not for the other(even when I add this second I get below output as error

```
plugin: azure.azcollection.azure_rm
include_vm_resource_groups:
  - <redacted>
  - <redacted>


auth_source: credential_file

keyed_groups:
  - prefix: tag
    key: tags
  - prefix: loc
    key: location
```

Error:

```
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-UFwkwC88/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py:44: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
  from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/user/project/ansible/inventories/azure/azure_rm.yaml with auto plugin: a batched request
failed with status code 404, url /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/user/project/ansible/inventories/azure/azure_rm.yaml with yaml plugin: Plugin
configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/user/project/ansible/inventories/azure/azure_rm.yaml with ini plugin: Invalid host
pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a port.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/user/project/ansible/inventories/azure/azure_rm.yaml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, I was trying to access virtual machines from different subscription ids.

To resolve this access issue I created profile in ~/.azure/credentials file

```
[profile_1]
subscription_id= xxx
tenant = xxx
client_id = xxx
secret = xxx

[profile_2]
subscription_id= xxx
tenant = xxx
client_id = xxx
secret = xxx
```

And created separate azure_rm.yaml files for these different subscription id like below

```
plugin: azure.azcollection.azure_rm
include_vm_resource_groups:
  - <rg in subscription 2>
auth_source: credential_file
profile: profile_2
```